# why is ntfswipe writing random values to undelete data?

Tags: disk-cleanup, ntfs-3g

was about to archive a harddrive as it came from the shop before adding my own OS on it, and given that it was a pre-used demo-machine bought at a discount, the harddrive was probably not clean behind-the-scenes, so i opted to run ntfswipe on it first (because 0x0000000000000000 compresses extremely well, duh),

```
root@xubuntu:/home/xubuntu# ntfswipe -a /dev/nvme0n1p3 
ntfswipe is about to wipe:
    unused disk space
    file tails
    unused mft areas
    unused directory index space
    the logfile (journal)
    the pagefile (swap space)
    undelete data

ntfswipe will overwrite these areas with: 0x00 
(however undelete data will be overwritten by random values)


ntfswipe will begin in 5 seconds, press CTRL-C to abort.

wipe_directory 0x00, 65016584 bytes
wipe_tails 0x00, 221482103 bytes
wipe_logfile 0xff, 67108864 bytes
wipe_mft 0x00, 187170816 bytes
wipe_pagefile 0x00, 5368709120 bytes
wipe_unused 0x00, 460829704192 bytes
wipe_undelete
466739191679 bytes were wiped (excluding undelete data)
```

the question here is, as stated in the title, why does it say:

```
(however undelete data will be overwritten by random values)
```

? when everything else is written over with 0x00 or 0xFF , why is the undelete data seemingly randomized?

Comment: If it's a NVMe disk and you're talking about compression, is it actually an SSD? I'm curious why you wouldn't be using `blkdiscard` or `fstrim` instead.

Comment: @grawity i'm making the ntfs partition as compressible as possible before i actually compress it onto another disk. idk about fstrim, but ntfswipe wipes `directory indexes which may contain names of deleted files`, `windows logfiles`, windows swap space, space between file content and the nearest allocation block (eg if you make a 1 byte file but the filesystem allocate 4096 bytes to store the 1 byte file because of blocksizes, ntfswipe will wipe the remaining 4095 bytes), unused space, and more, which i guess is more than fstrim will do?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, it performs a different kind of wipe.

Comment: @grawity on a related note, after archiving the original system, i would love to tell the ssd `*none* of the data is in use`, i don't know how to do that, think i am looking for blkdiscard / fstrim then ? :D - edit: yeah, after reading the blkdiscard  docs, that seems like will do it!

Comment: Yes, _that_ step can be done via `blkdiscard` if you want to nuke the entire thing, or via `fstrim` if you only want to clean up "unused" areas and leave the filesystem intact.

Comment: I assume it does that so the data isn't retrievable?  Is there a way to make it use `0x00` everywhere?